# Permission denied when running without bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script which calls some other bash, python, and ruby scripts. The script is similar to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

./aux1.py
./aux2.sh
```

When I run the script from the command line, it runs but it gives me the following output:

```
./script.sh: line 5: ./aux1.py: Permission denied
```

The `aux.py` script has `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top; when I call it from the command line with `./aux.py` it is fine, however when called from this script in the exact same way I get this error. The strange part is that this only happens when I run the script with `./script.sh`; when I run the script with `bash script.sh` the auxilliary scripts work perfectly.

I'm using Linux, why does this happen?

---

*Update, 3 March 2014*

There's nothing conflicting in the `PATH`, and all of the scripts are chmod `+rx`. `uname -srvmo` gives

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 13 06:58:20 EST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and there's no more information available in `uname -a`. SELinux is enabled, but I'm not an administrator so I can't access that information.

Comment: I should add that all of the scripts (`script.sh`, `aux1.py`, and `aux2.py`) have read and execute permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped when i copied it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it on my Fedora 19 system. Could you also post your `aux1.py`?

Comment: If you really do have `+x` permission on the file, make sure the filesystem isn't mounted with the `noexec` option.

Comment: Also, check that your file has native UNIX newlines; if you had DOS newlines, then `#!/usr/bin/env python` would actually be looking for an interpreter called `python^M`, not `python`.

Comment: If you showed evidence of the `+x` permissions in your question (ie. output of `ls -l aux1.py`), that's a thing we'd appreciate; better than having to dig through comments to find the assertion.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: By the way, as an aside, using extensions on scripts (`.py`, `.sh`, etc) is considered bad practice. See https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful for a longer discussion. (`.sh` is particularly wrong for bash scripts, as bash scripts are not guaranteed compatible with POSIX sh, though POSIX sh scripts are guaranteed compatible with bash).

Comment: Did you check for any hidden, unwanted characters in `script.sh` round that failing line (line 5)? You could check `od -c script.sh`, or make a new version from scratch being it's quite small and try again.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Comments by the OP have claimed that OS-level permissions are present, and follow-up questions (about filesystem mount options, hidden characters, etc) have not been responded to.

Comment: Any chance that the files might have `+x` but not `+r`? Both are necessary.

Comment: My guess is that there is another copy of `aux.py` floating around. You should put it into your `PATH` somewhere so the `./` is not needed...

Comment: @beroe, putting `.` into the PATH is bad practice for security reasons -- once upon a time, that was commonly done on shared university systems; it stopped for a reason (folks naming scripts which would delete one's files / allow entry to one's account as typos of common commands in /tmp was one of the common but less-inventive attacks).

Comment: @beroe ...and, well, using the `./` makes it **more** clear which copy of the one is to be invoked, not less, and **prevents** anything on the PATH from interfering.

Comment: `.` is not a part of the path.

Comment: @RCHowe, include the output from `cat /proc/mounts` in your question -- if not the full output, at least the line for the mount point the script is under.

Comment: @RCHowe, also, have you followed the instructions given by **any** of the people who were trying to determine whether your shebang or your script contained hidden characters? (mbratch, for instance, and also myself a few days ago).

Comment: ...it would be helpful if, instead of giving us information we never asked for (nobody asked for uname output, and the person who talked about PATH conflicts was already told why no such conflict could occur here), you gave us what we actually told you we needed.

Comment: `cat /proc/mounts` for the mount point the script is under gives `ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0`.

Comment: When I ran `od -c` the script showed no hidden characters.

Comment: @RCHowe ...and were newlines rendered as `\r\n` or `\n`? Likewise, did you check only the calling script, or did you also check the shebang of the callee? Thank you for the mount table -- that rules out `noexec` as a cause, though it leaves in SELinux (which you'd need help from your local sysadmin to diagnose).

Comment: All scripts are in UNIX newline format (as all were written by me in vim). All scripts have shebangs.

Answer (score 0):

Before launching the main script you must be sure that all the subscripts have got the right permissions. In particular you are interested in the permission for you (your user and owner of the files) to **execute** the file. This is a short tutorial on permissions. 
http://blog.pluralsight.com/linux-file-permissions
http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

If this is the problem (and it look so), the simpler solution is to run the following commands

```
chmod u+x script.sh aux1.py aux2.sh
```

To check whether you have permission to execute simply run

```
ls -l
```

You should see something like

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 youruser youruser 26 Feb 28 21:44 script.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 youruser youruser 32 Feb 28 21:44 aux1.py
```

where you should see a "x" in the 4th column corresponding to the file.

Comment: There's a deleted answer with the same diagnosis and solution; the OP commented on it claiming that all files have execute permission.

Comment: ...if the OP's claims in this respect are genuinely true, it's possible that this may be on a filesystem mounted with the noexec flag, or a similar restriction applied via different means (SELinux process-label-based restrictions, &c)

Comment: You are right, it might be so. May not he simply post the outputs of `ls -l` on the working directory and `mount` here? So we can check this option.

Comment: I asked him to do so hours ago; there's been no response -- hence the vote-to-close w/ insufficient info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe type `sudo su` before running your script so that you are the **root** user. When the script completes simply type `exit` to get out of root. Type `exit` again to close the shell.

:D

Comment: he probably does't want to run this scrips as root, and also running it from the shell is ok, so that does's seem to be the problem

Comment: Well I tried. It may work. If he is `root` there should be not permission problems. I did not mean to somehow imply that shell scripts are negative things by the way (btw) not sure how you reached that conclusion. Shell scripts rock. lol.

Comment: @user_loser, files without +x can't be executed with the `exec()` family of syscalls even by root.

Comment: ...well, there **is** a possibility here that they have `+x` but not `+r`. In that case, being root would make a difference, but just setting +r would be the right thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fascinating... I did not know this. Maybe using `chmod +x` is a good idea?

Comment: Well, the OP has claimed (in a comment on a deleted answer) that the files all already have +x, but they've ignored requests to provide proof of that (such as output from `ls -l`).

Comment: The policy that only high-rep users can see deleted answers is actually a bit annoying right now, as the comment history on provided-but-withdrawn answers is interesting/relevant to folks adding new answers on this question.

Comment: Interesting. I am sort of new to stackoverflow so I am not familiar with all the features.  I run shell scripts everyday to stop services in my LAMP stack. I always have to sudo into root and then exit out for the .sh script to work properly.

Comment: Sure, but the question here isn't about "work[ing] properly", but about being executable at all. As long as the `+x` bit is set everywhere, the shebang will be interpreted -- and since `python aux1.py` works, it's not anything *inside* the script that needs permissions it can't get.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I wonder what happened to OP. He has not tried any of these suggestions apparently.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy apparently he added an extra folder in the shebang. Some sort of env folder.  My knowledge is obviously limited in this area. It seems like a `sudo su` command would give all the permissions needed before running the shell script without the bash keyword.

Comment: @user_loser, `/usr/bin/env` is a program which first applies any environment variable changes specified at the beginning of its command line (hence its name) and then does a PATH lookup to find the program specified later in its command line to run that. `#!/usr/bin/env python` is the correct shebang to use when you want the first Python interpreter in the PATH to be used.

Comment: @user_loser ...by the way, on UNIX, it's spelled "directory", not "folder". That's why `ls -l` shows them with `d` at the beginning, and it's `-type d` in find, etc.

Comment: oh is this the etc/environment file? with PATH, etc? Maybe he does not have the correct settings here? I set JAVA_HOME here for instance. Maybe he needs something similar with Python? When I have coded with Python I never had to do that but...anyway. Sorry about the folders and directory error thing. lol.  I think of them as the same thing sitting on a file system.  I guess you are correct though. Especially considering the `mkdir` command will make a directory and not a folder.:D

Comment: @user_loser, no, `/usr/bin/env` is unrelated to `/etc/environment`. The way it's being used here, there *are* no environment variables specified, so it's used only to run a PATH lookup. I mentioned the support for applying changes for completeness.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48983/discussion-between-user-loser-and-charles-duffy)