# Permission denied when executing bash script without specifying shell

Tags: bash

*Similar to (and maybe possible duplicate): [Permission denied when running without bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104064/permission-denied-when-running-without-bash)*

On a linux server I have ssh access to (unsure of the distribution, but probably fedora), I have created a bash script (~/script.sh) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Filbo"
```

I then did the following:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh # doesn't have permission to run
-bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied
$ sudo ./script.sh # sudo not in $PATH
-bash: sudo: command not found
$ /bin/bash script.sh # it runs when I specify the shell to use
Filbo
```

There are obviously some interesting permissions on this server, but I don't understand exactly what's going on. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

P.S. there is no problem to solve (I can run it when I use bash), I would just like information

Comment: Add a `set -x` at the beginning of `script.sh` and analyze the output.

Comment: Have you tried `bash script.sh` ?

Comment: It may be SELinux that is blocking direct execution of your script.  Here's a question over at ServerFault about a situation that may be similar to yours, though solution given will not apply to your case: https://serverfault.com/questions/588019/selinux-access-denied-error-for-bash-scripts-triggered-from-perl-cgi-script

Comment: @quantik Sorry, used wrong name on the last command, see edit

Comment: @ratskin so `bash script.sh` works?

Comment: @ceving, that doesn't help in this situation, because the issue is in running the command. Though, just for you, here is the output: `$ bash script.sh
+ echo Filbo
Filbo
$ ./script.sh
-bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: @quantik yes, as you can see in my edited question

Comment: Well then you'd have to add location of the script to your PATH to run it without the `bash` by adding the location of the file to your `export PATH=$PATH:/appropriate/directory`

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think you may be right. It's not my server though, so I don't know about the configuration of it (not even the distro, but I think it's fedora). Looking at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux_FAQ#How_do_I_find_out_if_SELinux_is_enabled_on_my_system.3F I ran the `sestatus` command, but that wasn't found, so maybe that's blocked as well?

Comment: @quantik I thought the same thing, but apparently not: 
`$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/my-user-name`
`$ ./script.sh`
`-bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: @ratskin, "command not found" is quite a different thing from "permission denied".  If the system is running Linux in the first place, then it is highly likely to have SELinux installed (albeit not necessarily enabled or running in enforcing mode).  Most likely, you simply don't have `sestatus` in your path.  You could try `/usr/sbin/sestatus` and `/sbin/sestatus`, but these are only guesses.

Comment: @JohnBollinger please add this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain what's happening here?
>
> P.S. there is no problem to solve, I would just like information

No one can give a definitive answer without more information.

Per your request, however, I have expanded my comments and I provide them as an answer:

Supposing that the remote server is running Linux, a reasonably likely explanation is that you are being denied permission to execute your script by mandatory access controls -- *i.e.* SELinux running in enforcing mode.  If you do not have administrative access to the server then there may not be anything you can do about it, but since the file belongs to you, it may be that you can to relabel it to solve the problem.  What label you might need to apply depends on local security policy, however, so really you would be best off taking this up with the sysadmin.

It is also possible that the file resides on a filesystem mounted with the `noexec` option, so that no files on it can be directly executed.  In that case, there is nothing you could do to make the file executable at that location.

In any case, if the remote machine is GNU/Linux then the problem is unlikely to be with the script's shebang line (it would require a rather customized distro for that to explain it, but that's not altogether outside the realm of possibility).  It certainly is not with whether the script is in your executable search path, because you are not relying on the path to locate the script in the first place.

You should be able to determine what kind of machine you're running on via the `uname` command.  If SELinux is installed on the machine, then you probably can determine whether it is enable via the `sestatus` command, but you might not have it in your default executable path.  On RedHat-family machines, it's standard location is /usr/sbin.